# Did Prophet Muhammad SAW send blessing upon himself?

Tags: salat, hadith, prophet-muhammad, prophet-ibrahim, darood

Assalamu Alaikum brothers in Islam,

Someone asked me a question and I didn't have a clear answer to this. Please clarify it for me.

Did the Holy Prophet Muhammad SAW himself read Darood E Ibrahim in his Salat? Did he send blessings upon himself?

If yes, please provide reference.

If No, Then why do we Muslims do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did the Prophet (SAW) himself fully adhere to the rules imposed on all Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/did-the-prophet-saw-himself-fully-adhere-to-the-rules-imposed-on-all-muslims)

Comment: I followed the link, but couldn't find the answer to this question.

Answer (score -1):

Before prophet Muhammad SAWS death salat was sent to Ibrahim and his family. After prophet's death blessings are sent up on him.

Comment: Do you have any evidences to support your claims? (see [answer]).