# ِDid Prophet Muhammad sin? If so, what was that?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sin

In the Qur'an, Allah instructs Muhammad to ask forgiveness for his sin

> So know, [O Muhammad], that there is no deity except Allah and **ask forgiveness for your sin** and for the believing men and believing women. And Allah knows of your movement and your resting place.. Surat Muhammad 47:19

My question is, does the Qur'an or hadith specify which sin(s) Muhammad committed? (If he committed sin(s)?)

Comment: -1 for Title as prophets are sin less.

Comment: @ali786 Please demonstrate that prophets are sinless, as the Qur'an seems to imply differently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the prophet sinless?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/215/is-the-prophet-sinless)

Comment: @Klutch you already know visited and answered the question on http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/215/is-the-prophet-sinless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prophets are free from major sins, but are not from minor humane shortcomings. However, even those shortcomings are considered as "sin" towards them (Prophets) and the Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W.) would seek forgiveness from Allah all the time.

Examples of such shortcomings are [vow to not to eat honey](http://sunnah.com/nasai/27/33), [turning his face away from Abdullah ibn Umm Maktum](http://sunnah.com/urn/680420), not saying "Insha Allah" (Surat Al-Kahf [23](http://quran.com/18/23)-[24](http://quran.com/18/24)) , etc. All these are considered as mistakes for us ordinary people, but as "sin" for him (S.A.W.).

Comment: Muhammad broke a promise not to eat honey, didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @Klutch . The sin wasn't that he broke the promise not to eat honey but it was that he made such a promise (he later lawfully retracted the promise). Allah does not allow us to promise to not do good permissible things for no reason.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an extract from the Commentary of Puya:

**[Pooya/Ali Commentary 47:19]**

> **Imam Jafar
> bin Muhammad as Sadiq said:** "Just as a flutter of wind or a strong
> shaking brings the dried leaves of a tree on the ground, istighfar
> helps man to get rid of sins."
>
> **Aqa Mahdi Puya says:** Istighfar is a
> request made to Allah to keep the supplicant free from sinning by His
> grace and mercy. It is the highest form of worship. Every true servant
> of Allah uses this means to stay away from falling unintentionally
> into the pit of sin and evil, but a divinely commissioned leader
> (Imam) not only prays for himself but also for those who follow him,
> because their welfare is his responsibility.

Prophets, according to the Qur'an, are infallible. This doesn't mean that they can't commit sin, rather it means that they won't because they are of the highest spiritual and intellectual consciousness. They see the reality of their actions as it truly is and it's consequences.

As for mistakes, they don't make mistakes in religious matters either, Nor in non-religious matters. Contradictory to what @shoerat had said.

For if the prophet made mistakes, then one could question all the decisions and actions of the Prophet.

In the Qur'an, it testifies that prophet and his household were purified a **thorough and Constant** purification:

> And establish prayer and give zakah and **obey Allah and His Messenger.** **Allah intends only to
> remove from you the impurity , O people of the [Prophet's] household,
> and to purify you with Thorough purification.** [Sahih International
> 33:33]

Allah constantly tells us to obey the Prophet. If the prophet was susceptible to committing sins or mistakes. Then this would not make sense.

Also in the Qur'an, Allah(swt) says that Sheytan promised to stay away from those who are infallible as he said that he would deceive everyone **except Allah's chosen servants**:

> **Except, among them, Your chosen servants.** [Sahih International 15:40]

Comment: 1  they should be the one who every muslim following them. 2 they always love to pray and do better 3 limitations of material body and natural weakness es that everybody have., don't allow them to work 24/7 and they force to pray allah in another way like zikr in bed or sleep

Comment: _Contradictory to what @shoerat had said_ <-- probably, that's a Shia perspective. I just found out that this question was already beautifully addressed from a Sunni point of view in [Is the prophet sinless?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/215/2880)

Comment: If the prophets are infallible, what sins were Allah talking about in Surah 47:19?

Comment: As I said before... In Arabic the word "**Istaag-faar**" also means to **seek protection** ... Hence if you read Shakir's translation.. it is translated as : **"So know that there is no god but Allah, and, ask protection for your fault and for the believing men and the believing women; and Allah knows the place of your returning and the place of your abiding." (47:19)**

Comment: Hence what I am saying is, there is no sin that the prophet is being asked to repent for... rather Allah is asking the Prophet to seek Allah's protection against any sin.

Comment: I assume mentioning of 33:33 can help us a lot, as the answerer submitted it nicely.