# Was Musa sinless?

Tags: tafseer, prophet-musa, infallability

I have read [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/215/was-the-prophet-sinless) question and I have also studied in school that Prophets are sinless. Today I read in the Quran that Moosa killed a man. [Here](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2213) are the verses that describe the scene. I read at another place that he 'accidentally' killed him. I don't find it accidental myself (Musa struck him with his fist and he died.) Are Prophets sinless? Even if he hit the guy with his fist, its considered a sin.

Comment: There are several explanations of this. In particular punching a person does not imply intention to kill, and the resulting death would be accidental, unintentional mistakes are not sins. Hitting a person is not a always a sin, in this particular case he was a defending a Muslim from a Harbi Kafir.

Comment: @UmH: If he was defending a 'Muslim' from a kafir, then why did he say no to him the second time he asked for help?

Comment: @UmH: "(18. So he became afraid, looking about in the city, when behold, the man who had sought his help the day before, called for his help (again). Musa said to him: "Verily, you are a plain misleader!'') (19. Then when he decided to seize the man who was an enemy to both of them, the man said: "O Musa! Is it your intention to kill me as you killed a man yesterday Your aim is nothing but to become a tyrant in the land, and not to be one of those who do right.'')"

Comment: I think that [verse 19](https://quran.com/28/19?translations=20,84) {http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2212} makes it clear that he did not refuse to help him the second time. Even if he did refuse, that does not mean that he had sinned by helping him the first time.

Comment: @UmH: If he did not commit a sin, why did he asked for forgiveness?

Comment: Is forgiveness only asked for sins? Prophets because of their high rank have a greater responsibility, they are upset on and sometimes even reprimanded for their mistakes, however it does not make those actions sins.

Comment: @UmH The seems to be a case of word gymnastics that you see many preacher do. The word in the Quran used is best described as "shortcoming or fault" sometime actaully translated as sin, now if something is your fault it is not a mistake, but preacher seem to makes these hurdle  in the English language to pass of their own belif

Comment: @UmH what do you mean by this "high rank have a greater responsibility", by this you are rejecting 112:2 of the Quran, and thus the whole of surah 112 and the very essence of oneness of God. Prophet were no-more than men

Comment: @AsanRamzan What word are you referring to? There is a distinction between mistake and sin, even if the words might at times be used interchangeably depending on the context. 
See for example [33:5](https://quran.com/33/5) وليس عليكم جناح فيما **أخطأتم** به ولكن ما تعمدت قلوبكم and [2:286](https://quran.com/2/286)  لا تؤاخذنا إن نسينا أو **أخطأنا** and [4:92](https://quran.com/2/286) أن يقتل مؤمنا إلا **خطأ**  and this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40/39) إن الله تجاوز لي عن أمتي **الخطأ** etc.

Comment: I don't see how this negates 112:2 or the rest of the Surah or the oneness of God, though that discussion seems off-topic. Please refer to my answer [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/52867/20218) as that might address some of your concerns.

Comment: @UmH I am referring to 48:2. and you find none of the translation have the word mistake: https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/48/2/default.htm. Also this word shortcoming seems to be used for some clear sinners in the Quran like the magicians in the time of Musa. But it is crystal clear that these messenger were only men like our selves 18:110, 16:43...(the reference are numerous)

Answer (score 4):

Note that عصمة of the Prophets is agreed upon by the Muslims, however they differed on what it entails and from when it is applicable. For example, according to the Ahlul Sunnah it entails protection from intentional sins but not mistakes and forgetfulness, for some also it entails protection from major sins but not from some minor sins. For some, such as the Shia, it entails protection from even mistakes.

The killing of the Egyptian by Moses (عليهم السلام) was not a sin, but an unintentional mistake. The evidence for this includes the hadith of the Prophet ﷺ:

> وإنما قتل موسى الذي قتل من آل فرعون خطأ
>
> Moses killed a person from among the people of Pharaoh unintentionally
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/54/63)</sup>

Further Mufassirs have also given the following explanations:

- The Egyptian was a Harbi, whose blood is permitted. At most it was preferable to handle the situation differently rather than to kill him. Leaving what is recommended for what is permitted is not a sin.
- He had not yet received Prophethood at the time of this incident, so the viewpoint of those who claim that infallibility is only after prophethood is satisfied.