# Who decided that the 6 Sahih Hadiths were reliable?

Tags: hadith

There are 6 collections of Hadiths that are considered Sahih ("reliable"). I am asking who it was that decided these collections should be Sahih. Furthermore, *how* did they come to this conclusion? For example, to determine the books that would make up the "official" Bible, the Council of Nicea was convened. So, was it a group of scholars, and if so who were they; or, if it was a single scholar, who was that? If there was some other means of determining, what was it? Thank you much.

Comment: [How do we make sure if an Hadith is sahih or fake?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-we-make-sure-if-an-hadith-is-sahih-or-fake) and [What are the requirements of a “Sahih” hadith?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23/what-are-the-requirements-of-a-sahih-hadith)

Comment: Works of Bukhari [Why are hadith considered an authoritative source in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/93/why-are-hadith-considered-an-authoritative-source-in-islam)

Comment: Can you please fully read the supposed duplicates before posting those. I believe this is the second or third time in which you have falsely considered my questions duplicates. Those questions state the general process by not who the final authority is. For example, there are 6 hadiths considered reliable by the Sunnis and 3 by the Shiite; someone or some group of determined these Hadiths to be reliable. I want to know who and when, not how.

Comment: This time I did not vote for duplicates. But again I'm telling you to look for valuable information available already. Thought it could help you. I'm sorry.

Comment: OK now to your question. There is no approved standard perfect widely accepted organization which everyone relies on. Everyone have different views even on a single verse of Qur'an which is so perfect. But, widely accepted by most of the scholars are those 'Sahih' Hadith. No single body is considered final. Although there are organizations which do a lot of research on the authenticity. I can't name them, they're many.

Comment: I know that, but when I type the question, I check the other similar questions to see if they answer my question. I have refrained from asking at least a dozen questions since I became a member of the stack exchange universe. The body of the question is where my question differentiates. I did not say it to be disrespectful, I say it because it seems that you have not read the question's answers thoroughly, and therefore do not understand why my question is different.

Comment: Can you post the source where you got that 6 books were considered Sahih? Because not even the books that are titled Sahih are 100% reliable and contain inauthentic hadiths.

Comment: @Sayyid This was not the original site I saw this, and I am trying to find the first one I saw. I will post that as well if I can find it. http://www.islam-fyi.com/general-knowledge/six-authentic-books-of-hadith-sihah-sitta

Comment: @servantofWiser Do you not post your answers in an answer form out of fear of being downvoted? As to your answer-comment: Someone called those 6 collections Sahih. Even if it was all of Islamdom, they had to come together and vote or have someone decide for them. These collections did not come into being as Sahih. It had to be determined somewhere, sometime, by someone.

Comment: Buddy you're wrong with both the points, I did not answer in the answer form, because I perfectly don't know the answer and that is the only reason why I thought of helping you by showing other existing answers. 2nd, Many of the muslims don't even care to read those so called Sahih Hadith, e.g. Shias. They don't rely on those. As I said, this religion Islam is not governed by priests or organisations as it is done in Christianity. Everyone has his own version. That is the main reason why those guys are holding guns for everything. Hope you'll understand

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here; I would guess you just want to know how the Kutub al-Sittah were chosen, but that's definitely not what you're *asking* (for one thing, the Kutub al-Sittah aren't "considered Sahih" by any major doctrine I know).  I would recommend you check out the [relevant Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kutub_al-Sittah) first and take the time to focus your question in more answerable form. (see also the help centre page on "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)")

Comment: This question was well received in the community, so maybe you could try askin  this one more time but taking suggestions in the chat maybe helpful. All the best. This is a good question actually.