# Is the Musnad Abu Hanifa authentically attributed to Imam Abu Hanifa?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

On Maktaba Shamela there is a book titled'

> مسند أبي حنيفة رواية الحصكفي 
> Musnad Abi Hanifa, the transmission of Haskafi

but inside the book I didn't find any chains from Imam Abu Hanifa to us. So I came here to ask is this book authentically attributed to the hand of Imam Abu Hanifa رحمه الله

Comment: "but inside the book I didn't find any chains from Imam Abu Hanifa to us" this is an expectation any hadith book will fail to achieve. Because the person who is sharing his hadith narrations or knowledge is usually the author (the person referring to) or one of his students.

Comment: thanks for the response but then how can a hadith book be authentically attributed to the alleged author

Comment: This is a question which was addressed in [Can any hadith truly be called sahih anymore](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/can-any-hadith-truly-be-called-sahih-anymore).