# Can animals see the angels and jinn and hear the cries of the dead?

Tags: authenticity, death, jinn, animals, malaikah

I recently heard a Sunni hadith that said roosters can see the angels at the time of fajar and that is why they make  that sound of theirs. And also donkeys cry when they see jinn or the shaithan. I am not sure if this hadith or its interpretation is authentic.

I have heard incidents where the Prophet has mentioned that animals can hear the cries of the people in barzakh. Makes sense to me because we don't see animals or birds near the graveyard.

So is the above true?

**EDIT:** The Hadith in question is:  Abu Huraira reported Allah’s Messenger as saying :” When you listen to the crowing of the rooster, ask Allah for His favor as it sees Angels and when you listen to the braying of the donkey, seek refuge in Allah from the Satan for it sees Satan. ([Muslim Book 035, Number 6581](https://sunnah.com/muslim/48/112)).

There is a very unscientific discussion [here](https://siheem.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/the-donkey-can-see-satan-and-the-rooster-can-see-angels/), as well. But that is not my point. I couldn't find Hadith anywhere else. Is it authentic?

Comment: @Envayo That is a good thought. Does it increase my Imaan? Not really. But whenever someone gives you Islamic Knowledge and tells you this about Hadiths, you have to make sure they are authentic. Now, some hadiths are well known and accepted. Then there are some, that is not clear or raises your eyebrow. The above is such a one (for me at least). So if this is true, I could continue trusting the source of information, else I will have to interfere. Spreading a wrong Hadith is like spreading lies in the name of the Prophet (PBUH). Hope you understand

Comment: @Envayo I partly agree with you. But since we have a platform like this, why not try at least? Best case scenario, some one gives me an answer. Else it remains unanswered, which tells me no body is interested in the question or the Hadith. Either way no harm done in asking right?

Comment: @Envayo thanks, then I correct myself, Quran is secured the same way it has been done for sahih hadith (and partly still is these days) by tawatur. This is at least one of the known ways Allah has secured His book. If there are other's then Allah may know them best. But that was the way our early scholars, especially the sahaba and tabi'yn decided what is considered as an approved Quran reading and what is not. On the other hand I must admit that we shouldn't take all of the hadith literally and cross-check it with Quran.

Answer (score 2):

**I have heard incidents where the Prophet has mentioned that animals can hear the cries of the people. Is it true?**

Yes.

#### Sahih Bukhari:

> Narrated Anas:
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "When a human being is laid in his grave and his companions return and he even hears their foot steps, two angels come to him and make him sit and ask him: What did you use to say about this man, Muhammad ? He will say: I testify that he is Allah's slave and His Apostle. Then it will be said to him, 'Look at your place in the Hell-Fire. Allah has given you a place in Paradise instead of it.' " The Prophet (ﷺ) added, "The dead person will see both his places. But a non-believer or a hypocrite will say to the angels, 'I do not know, but I used to say what the people used to say! It will be said to him, 'Neither did you know nor did you take the guidance (by reciting the Qur'an).' Then he will be hit with an iron hammer between his two ears, and he will cry and that cry will be heard by whatever approaches him except human beings and jinns." ~ [Sahih al-Bukhari 1338](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1338)
>
> Narrated `Aisha:
> Two old ladies from among the Jewish ladies entered upon me and said' "The dead are punished in their graves," but I thought they were telling a lie and did not believe them in the beginning. When they went away and the Prophet (ﷺ) entered upon me, I said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Two old ladies.." and told him the whole story. He said, "They told the truth; the dead are really punished, to the extent that all the animals hear (the sound resulting from) their punishment." Since then I always saw him seeking refuge with Allah from the punishment of the grave in his prayers. ~ [Sahih al-Bukhari 6366](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/63)

Answer (score 1):

The hadith you are referring to is in [Sahih Bukhari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahih_al-Bukhari) and [Sahih Muslim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahih_Muslim) (see below).  Generally, both of these are considered about about as authentic as it gets in terms of hadith.  See the top answer to [Is Sahih al-Bukhari considered as 100% authentic by Sunni scholars?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2419/17163).

#### Sahih Bukhari:

> Narrated Abu Huraira: The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "When you hear the crowing of cocks, ask for Allah's Blessings for (their crowing indicates that) they have seen an angel. And when you hear the braying of donkeys, seek Refuge with Allah from Satan for (their braying indicates) that they have seen a Satan." -- [Sahih al-Bukhari 3303](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/111)

#### Sahih Muslim:

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying. When you listen to the crowing of the cock, ask Allah for His favour as it sees Angels and when you listen to the braying of the donkey, seek refuge in Allah from the Satan for it sees Satan. -- [Sahih Muslim 2729](https://sunnah.com/muslim/48/112)

Comment: So,also dogs when they see an invisible enemy approaching to their master like the devil then the dogs will bark at the devil? Or when the devil is approaching to their territory then they'll bark at the devil?

Comment: Hmm.. the question has changed since I answered it.  By reading the above hadith, you know what I know; I cannot reliably go beyond what I've written e.g. by interpreting these ahadith.

Answer (score 0):

I checked some science channels to check for it...there s definitely some difference in the eyes of humans and animals...we r limited for our vision but some animals have superceeded us in this
As for chicken or the rooster, their colour vision is more stronger than humans as they have 5 types of light receptors in their retina, their ability to see in the day light and to differentiate between colour wavelength is very strong than that of humans.
https://www.livescience.com/8099-chickens-color-humans.html

its an article of live science website presented in 2010, u can read the details

Second for the donkeys too its been explored that their far vision and night vision is too much stronger than humans, and to some extent their sense of hearing is also marvellous

there are other animals with great eyesight like eagles and other predators bt these are wild animals

while chicken and donkeys animals are found everywhere in our towns and farms, thats why there names were mentioned in this hadith so that ppl can remains aware of their surrounding, as though they cant see bt their accompanying animals can see and inform them about the surroundings.

Rest Allah s the best knowing of all

thanks and jazakAllah kher