# Do hens crowing indicate seeing an angel?

Tags: hadith, malaikah, animals

In my house there are many chickens, and we used to hear the chicken crow many times in a day. Does this means that our chickens have seen angels that many times a day?

A relevant hadith is:

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying. When you listen to the crowing of the cock, ask Allah for His favour as it sees Angels and when you listen to the braying of the donkey, seek refuge in Allah from the Satan for it sees Satan. -- Sahih Muslim 2729 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/48/112))

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33383/can-animals-see-the-angels-and-jinn-and-hear-the-cries-of-the-dead

Comment: I heard a sheikh say that these are context specific i.e crowing of the cock early morning implies it sees angels & braying of donkey & barking of dogs at night indicate they see the bad jinns (shayateen).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does as the Hadith says. Another Hadith is :
The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Do not revile the rooster for it wakes you up for prayer." 
The early morning prayer is Fajr which one wakes up to pray. At Fajr time, the angels move around to listen to your prayer and thus the hen/rooster sees the angels and crows which will wake you up to pray. 
Three voices that are loved by Allah, namely: the voice of the roosters, the voice of one who is reading Qur'an and the voice of the one who calls for forgiveness before the break of day.

http://islam.ru/en/content/story/invocation-upon-hearing-cocks-crow

Answer (score -1):

i live in a quite remote village with only 19 house in it. no need to ask, my village gone siren at 8 PM, and gone completely pitch black when everyone gone to sleep, not even a streetlight exist, Yet, roosters sometimes do crow at 2 or 3 AM, and Its denying almost all the scientific reason i could find online until i heard bout this. Did some research and found that angel are said created from light. then if roosters can indeed see angels, its kind of make sense they would crow even in a pitch black night as they probably mistaken the angels as Dawn.