# The Prophet Muhamamd (s.a.w) pardoned a apostate from Islam?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

We know that the majority of scholars say if anyone leaves the religion of Islam the punishment is death but according to this hadith he pardoned them can you explain this hadith?

Narrated Jabir:
that a Bedouin gave the pledge to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) for Islam, then he was afflicted by the sickness in Al-Madinah. So the Bedouin went to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and said: "Take back my pledge." But the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) refused. Then the Bedouin left and came back and said: "Take back my pledge," and he refused. Then the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Al-Madinah is but like bellows, it expels its filth and purifies its good."

Grade   : Sahih (Darussalam)
English reference    : Vol. 1, Book 46, Hadith 3920
Arabic reference     : Book 49, Hadith 4299

Comment: if you speak arabic, i recommend this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5GdzA7zVWw

Comment: or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EonUAQ3ztgM by the scholar (rahimahu Allah)

Comment: @Kilise i think adnan ibrahim is not considered a good source for Islamic scholars view !!

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi define good source. You can disagree with him as most of the salafi scholars do. That is OK.

Comment: do you think malik , abu-hanifah, chfaii and others are salafis ??

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi when I say salafi scholars I mean todays so called salafi scholars.

Comment: you said salafi scholars are disagree with him ,well  i think a'ima are disagree  with him too :) because he refuse a lot of texts ! 
i didn't speak about salafi scholars you did !!

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi it's ok to disagree. But you shouldn't say he isn't a good source. I may disagree with him about certain issues too and many I agree with him about .

Comment: @Kilise well yes , you are right but in my opinion he is not a good source ! :)

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi what is a good source?

Comment: @Kilise don't get it like this :) my friend i am not trying to force people to follow  the ones i am following . in my opinion people who refuse hadith and sunna or reject it , is not a good source in the issues he is refusing hadith !  to be honest the majority of adnan fatawa who goes against the current had be said by big modern scholars , but collecting them all in one person is like Following licenses ! remember this is my opinion

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi He isn't refusing the hadiths or the sunnah, he might reject one or two, but that is pretty normal. Look at Med1Saifs answer here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/is-sahih-al-bukhari-considered-as-100-authentic-by-sunni-scholars

Comment: @Kilise this is Medi1saif opinion , maybe based on a rational rule or something else , but for my current knowledge criticism bukhari and muslim doesn't make those ahadith weak :) even al-albani credited  some !!
i don't want to make this a conversation but there is problems with adnan and his current Speech , even Medi1saif admit this

Comment: @Kilise i am not trying to be rude or to change your opinion about the man he is good in a lot of things  , but the main problem that a lot of people is agree about , is that adnan ibrahim talk about a'iima and big scholars with a non-respectable way  " Demolition of role models  " !!  . if you are living in an arabic country you will notice how people respect to scholars will change after listen to ibrahim for a while . may allah guide us to the truth