# Can this be called a Hadith?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

The following link quotes a snippet:

> A young boy had a dream; ‘In the dream, I saw myself in a huge, flat area.
>   I saw an army mounted on white horses moving towards me. All of them were wearing black turbans. One of the horsemen... had shiny eyes... He moved a flag towards me and said, “Hand this flag over to Imam Mahdi Muhammad bin Abdullah at the gates of Al-Quds (Jerusalem).” I took the flag from him, and I saw that the army started marching behind me.’

[http://salaf-stories.blogspot.in](http://salaf-stories.blogspot.in/2013/12/ebook-black-flags-from-khurasan.html)

So from which primary Islamic book does the above snippet come from and is it authentic, and can this even be called a "hadith"?

Comment: The linked source doesn't in any way claim it is a hadith, so what reason would you have for even asking if it is, or why you would expect to find it *in* any of the primary Islamic books?

Comment: Of course, No. This looks a man-made story.

Answer (score 2):

Hadith = "News" in Arabic.

In general, Hadith pertain to the news or information about the narrations of Prophet Muhammad(peace be upon him).

Your quoted hadith do not pertain to Prophet (peace be upon him) and hence cannot be considered into account. And moreover, there isn't any ruling or law, but it was just about a dream, so it could be a controversial issue.

Anyways, in general, there are Research organizations specifically meant for this and are doing good.

More info in this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-we-make-sure-if-an-hadith-is-sahih-or-fake?rq=1)

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                     In the name of Allah
```

As the famous expression of Elme-Hadith (the science of tradition), hadith would be termed as a speech which indicates the practice or utterance of the prophet Muhammad (S) (and his Ahlul-Bayt).

Furthermore as Mr. goldPseudo declared "The linked source doesn't in any way claim it is a hadith,” . on the other hand, as the user “Mr. Wiser” mentioned, this solely a dream; As an Islamic rule, all the dreams could not be considered as real truths. On the whole, the significant point is related to the authenticity of the matter above.

And God knows best

Reference:

[www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=40384)