# Is basing the authenticity of a hadith based on its source even right?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith

I always thought that only **sahih albukhari** and **sahih muslim** are the only 100% correct sources of hadiths and pretty much ignored other sources until I found this thread:  [How do we make sure if a Hadith is sahih or fake?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-we-make-sure-if-a-hadith-is-sahih-or-fake)

My question is: Is basing the authenticity of a hadith based on its source even right?

Can someone consider the sources above 100% true? and is there any other sources to be considered as true so one can easily learn from from them without having the trouble to check authenticity for a hadith each time, which will create some unwanted doubt in every hadith heard?

Comment: There's no 100% sahih hadith book! Al-Bukhari and Muslim did a big effort or great attempts, but they in best case reached 80-99%. Others also have sahih beside less reliable ahadith among the sahih books there's al-Muwatta' (if you take only the ahadith -only the prophetic traditions-in it) among the sunan the one of abu Dawod doesn't even reach 60% of sahih narrations. Note that now it seems hard to qualify a hadith based on tawatur, as since all ahadith have been compiled, the different narrator chains al-Bukhari and co didn't mention or left out maybe lost!

Comment: @Medi1Saif do you recommand some good sources to check for a hadith, website, a person or any other source really. because Im in an arab country, and our primary cause for becoming (staying) muslims is because our parents are! i like how foreign people, or people who convert look for the truth and study islam, try to understand quran the best way, im not trying to make the image negative but it can be sometimes very confusing ! thanks you !

Comment: My recommendation is start understanding the qur'an first if a hadith seems contradictory to the teachings of qur'an start doubting it's authenticity! Or start doing further investigation on sunnah.com you may find the most known hadith collections!